# Integration Angular project into React

Tags: angular, reactjs

I have two project one is React is website and other is Angular and it's widget (login, registration, profile,...etc) anyone have an idea how we can integrate them together?

Comment: Is the angular javascript or TS?

Can you post the sample code

Comment: This totally depends on projects and the exact meaning of 'integrate'.

Answer (score 0):

With [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements), you can export an Angular component as HTML custom element. Once exported, you can use it like any normal HTML element in your React code.

The Angular team used this approach on their documentation site to include formatted source code examples. If you look at the page source code of the Angular Elements documentation, you will find a `<code-example>` tag.